Sum row values when first column data is equal
How to sum data in 2nd column for same values in column 1:
c = [11 1;
     11 3;
     12 5;
     13 9;
     13 11;
     13 3]

expected result is:
r = [11 4;
     12 5;
     13 23]

I know how to manage this using a loop but is there another easier way? In Matlab the function accumarray would work but is there something similar in Scilab?

Could you show how Scilab works here?

In Scilab, here is a solution without explicit for loop, provided that c's first column is already sorted:
i =  [c(2:$,1)~=c(1:$-1,1) ; %T];
tmp = [0 ; cumsum(c,"r")(i, 2)];
res = [c(i,1), tmp(2:$)-tmp(1:$-1)]

yielding
--> res = [c(i,1), tmp(2:$)-tmp(1:$-1)]
 res = [3x2 double]
   11.   4. 
   12.   5. 
   13.   23.


Find below a solution, may be not the best one
[c,k]=gsort(c,'r','i');
i=find(c(1:$-1,1)<>c(2:$,1));
r=[];l=1;
for j=[i(1:$),size(c,1)]
   r=[r;c(j,1),sum(c(l:j,2))];
   l=j+1;
end


>> table2array(removevars(groupsummary(array2table(c), "c1","sum"),'GroupCount'))

ans =

    11     4
    12     5
    13    23


or
>> [unique(c(:,1)),accumarray(findgroups(c(:,1)),c(:,2))]

ans =

    11     4
    12     5
    13    23

